# Is the logic in my program close in terms of arriving to the solution?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I'm trying to count the number of times a letter appears in a string (`aabcccccaaa`) and placing the number of times that it does into a new string along with the corresponding letter.  The problem's that I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I kind of have a clue why but I think it's mainly because my logic is flawed with this problem.

Am I on the right track?  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

For example, the output should be `a2b1c5a3`

Here's my code:

```
public class Problem {

public static void main(String []args) {
    String str = "aabcccccaaa";
    System.out.println(compressBad(str));
}

public static String compressBad(String str) {
    int countConsecutive = 0;
    String compressedString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            countConsecutive++;
            compressedString += "" + str.charAt(i) + countConsecutive;
            countConsecutive = 0;
        }
    }
    return compressedString;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This line `str.charAt(i + 1)` will read out of bounds when `i` is the last index, `i+1` is now out of bounds.

Comment: ok, I got that.  But in terms of arriving to the solution, am I almost correct in terms of the logic after the `str.charAt(i + 1)`?

Comment: He explained the reason for the exception, your code does have more mistakes in it, debug the program to find out what goes wrong any why. That's the only way to learn

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's what I would do :

```
public static String compressBad(final String str) {

    if (str == null || str.length() < 0) {
        return "";
    }

    int countConsecutive = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char previousLetter = str.charAt(0);

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == previousLetter) {
            countConsecutive++;
        } else {
            sb.append(previousLetter).append(countConsecutive);

            previousLetter = c;
            countConsecutive = 1;
        }
    }
    sb.append(previousLetter).append(countConsecutive);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: cool, I appreciate this answer :D.  But I wanted to solve this solution the way I approached it.